# Send via bluetooth doesn't work on Android 2.X

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

Hi I'm trying to send a file via bluetooth but I have a problem with android 2.X (note that it works on android 4.X). Here is my code:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.bluetooth", 
        "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

When it gets to the startActivity(sharingIntent) line it throws an exception:

```
12-21 17:09:43.379: W/System.err(29452): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.bluetooth/com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-21 17:09:43.379: W/System.err(29452):        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
12-21 17:09:43.379: W/System.err(29452):        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
12-21 17:09:43.379: W/System.err(29452):        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
12-21 17:09:43.379: W/System.err(29452):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:833)
12-21 17:09:43.379: W/System.err(29452):        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:856)
...
```

Declaring the activity in manifest doesn't work.

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've face this problem but not in every device. You can use a workaround by detecting the OS version, and if its lower than 11, use the setPackage() method. Also use an Intent chooser to prevent crashing.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
        sharingIntent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
    }else{
        sharingIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.bluetooth", 
                "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
    }

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share"));
```

Hope it helps!